# Insert hundreds of rows into Google spreadsheet with Zend Gdata?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, google-sheets

Inserting rows one by one from a 600 record data-set is taking almost an hour, using the following method:

```
foreach($people as $person){
    $insert['name'] = $associate -> name;
    $insertedListEntry = $spreadsheetService->insertRow($insert, $spreadsheetKey, $worksheetId);
}
```

Is it possible to insert multiple rows at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. See [the official Google response on this.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=5db19d43cb454e7e&hl=en)

They do suggest parallelizing your requests to speed up the insertion process.